# what is the result of this proc in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I have a question about the following proc:

```
proc setDefault {{nampspaceList "ALL"}} {
    if {$nampspaceList == "ALL"} {
        set nampspaceList "namespace1 namespace2 namespace3"
    }
    foreach ns $nampspaceList {
        append ns "::setDefault"
        $ns
    }
}
```

The appended ns is "::setDefaultnamespace1namespace2namespace3", but what is the meaning of &ns in foreach loop, everytime append a namespace, it will print out the result once?

Comment: You ask about the meaning of `&ns` but I don't see such a string in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foreach` loop in your procedure is looping through the list held in the variable `nampspaceList`, and for each item in the list it is creating a command by appending `::setDefault` to it.

The line `$ns` then attempts to execute that command.

Comment: Moreover, the argument (or default) is not updated _at all_ by this; Tcl copies values. (Strictly, it uses a copy-on-write reference management scheme that's smarter than stupid copying, but the _semantics_ are identical to an eager string duplication.)

Answer (score 1):

Ehm, no, the final value of ns after running the foreach loop is "[lindex $nampspaceList end]::setDefault", because in each iteration ns is set with each item in the list $nampspaceList.

You could check that by adding a few puts in the middle of the code.

For instance calling it with: `setDefault {ns1 ns2 ns3}`
will have ns set to `ns1::setDefault` (after the append of "::setDefault"), `ns2::setDefault` and `ns3::setDefault`.